# Was Grogu under some form of suspended animation in his ball when initially being held?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

I was recently rereading some of the reviews of the early episodes of the *The Mandalorian*, when I had a question from the first episode come back to me. When Din initially finds Grogu, and opens the capsule (identified as a hover pram on [the Fandom wiki entry for the episode](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_1:_The_Mandalorian)), it's not made clear exactly what the state of "the asset" is other than Din's commentary about them not looking like a fifty-year-old. Was Grogu in a form of suspended animation? Had the Nikto bandits simply been caring for him the whole time they had him? It doesn't seem to have been covered up to Season 3, Episode 3, which is where I am, but I know there are at least two junior novelizations (I read the Golden Book one, and I have seen one other being sold), and I suspect there may be other extended material out there.

Comment: I believe there's an early episode where the characters conclude that Grogu's species must be long-lived, precisely because he still acts like a toddler despite being 50+ years old. So they clearly think he's been aging normally this whole time, although they could be wrong about that.

Comment: @Withad So if he's been aging normally, the other part of this question is. . . Who was caring for him and why? Were the bandits keeping him fed?

Comment: @Turbo - Seems like they're deliberately leaving that a mystery, although they're very slowly explaining it with flashbacks.

Comment: If _The Mandalorian_ was 80% just showing me Grogu getting plenty of snacks and healthy meals throughout his timeline, I’d still be pretty happy with it.

Comment: @Withad It's at least said in the first episode. Mando: "Wait. They said 50 years old." IG-11: "Species age differently. Perhaps it could live many centuries."

Comment: {nods} It's less a matter of "not aging during that time" as that it just feels weird to think that whatever groups have been passing him along take him out every "X" amount of time to feed, play with him, etc.

Comment: They might not have been playing with him, which might mean that he’s a bit less developed than you’d expect for an average 50-ish-year-old of his species. Challenging to hit, milestones can be.

Comment: Additionally, are there any forms of suspended animation outside of carbonite freezing in the SW universe?

Comment: I want to say there have been a few cases of hibernation in the EU, primarily to explain various force clones waking up somewhere else.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots there could be a Droids 1985 style series where Grogu hitchhikes through the Galaxy

Comment: I'm given to understand that one of the more recent episodes explains a little about what happened between the Jedi Temple and Din finding him, but my wife will kill me if I watch them without her. :-D

Comment: *"Mando held the tracker in front of him, walking forward as the beeping intensified, following the signal until he found himself looking at a silver egg-shaped container hovering just above the floor. Leaning down, he tapped a release button, and the cover sprang open to reveal a small shape partially covered by a blanket."* - Nothing in the novelisation to indicate it's anything other than a metal ball sat on a suspensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valorum posted from one of the novelizations:

> Mando held the tracker in front of him, walking forward as the beeping intensified, following the signal until he found himself looking at a silver egg-shaped container hovering just above the floor. Leaning down, he tapped a release button, and the cover sprang open to reveal a small shape partially covered by a blanket.

So it sounds like the container was not actually doing anything other than physically holding Grogu in. Until further information comes in, I will assume that this is the answer.